# Iterating Through a C# Object

Tags: c#

I am looking for the most efficient way of iterating through attributes within an object and checking to see if it has a custom decorator. The challenge is that my object has other objects within it that may have this custom decorator and the SUB-Objects may have objects as well with decorators.

For now the code down below is only reaching into the first layer of sub objects is there a particular way in which I can go within the loop N times efficiently?

```
List<PropertyInfo> allProperties = type.GetProperties().ToList();

Dictionary<string, List<string>> groupIndexes = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
{
    var nestedProperties = property.PropertyType.GetProperties();
    foreach (var nestedProperty in nestedProperties)
    {
        var singleNestedPropertyIndex = nestedProperty.GetCustomAttribute<SingleIndexAttribute>();
        var groupNestedIndex = nestedProperty.GetCustomAttribute<GroupIndexAttribute>();
        var ttlIndex = property.GetCustomAttribute<TTLIndexAttribute>();

        if (singleNestedPropertyIndex != null || groupNestedIndex != null || ttlIndex != null)
        {
            allProperties.Add(nestedProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do it in a recursive method.

Comment: ..or explicitly use `Stack<T>`. Implementing `Breadth-first search` or `Depth-first search` could solve your problem. Both can be done using recursion or stack.

Comment: @pkuderov That is definitely more helpful, I need to determine WHEN to stop iterating basically when the inner attribubte has no more complex attributes.

Comment: Important question: *do your objects ever form a cycle*?  That is, do you ever have a case where A has sub-object B, has sub-object C, has sub-object D, has sub-object A?  Because if you do then the algorithm needs to be written cleverly so that it does not go into infinite loops or recursions.

Comment: @MongZhu that is incorrect, there are plenty of classes with no properties which you would never get a IsValueType true with

Comment: @MongZhu: And there are plenty of value types that refer to reference types. Your claim is simply wrong.

Comment: You say you want the **most efficient** algorithm. Efficiency is defined as value achieved per unit of work. So, two questions: (1) how do you measure value and work? *be precise*. And (2) **how much are you willing to spend to achieve the greatest possible efficiency**?  Millions? Billions?  Achieving *the highest possible efficiency* is going to be an expensive proposition. I think perhaps you don't actually want the most efficient solution; I suspect you want a *reasonably performant solution that takes about ten minutes to implement*.

Comment: @EricLippert indeed!

Comment: @EricLippert thank you for the enlightment I removed my comment. Truely, I did not think of strings and array or lists or that kind.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thank you for the enlightment I removed my comment. Truely, I did not think of strings and array or lists or that kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform it by creating recursive method;

```
    public static void FindSpecialProperties(PropertyInfo property, List<PropertyInfo> allProperties, HashSet<PropertyInfo> recursivedProperties)
    {
        if (recursivedProperties.Contains(property))//Eliminate already recursived property
        {
            return;
        }
        recursivedProperties.Add(property);
        var properties = property.PropertyType.GetProperties();
        if (properties.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            var singleNestedPropertyIndex = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<SingleIndexAttribute>();
            var groupNestedIndex = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<GroupIndexAttribute>();
            var ttlIndex = property.GetCustomAttribute<TTLIndexAttribute>();

            if (singleNestedPropertyIndex != null || groupNestedIndex != null || ttlIndex != null)
            {
                allProperties.Add(propertyInfo);
            }
            allProperties.Add(propertyInfo);
            FindSpecialProperties(propertyInfo, allProperties, recursivedProperties);
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
        var recursivedProperties = new HashSet<PropertyInfo>();
        var allProperties = type.GetProperties().ToList();
        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            FindSpecialProperties(property, allProperties, recursivedProperties);
        }
```

Comment: Be careful, with this current code if you have a cycle (Class A has a property of B, B has a property of C, and C has a property of A) you can get in to a infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you I will test this as well since I need to do it recursively. I will test it out.

Comment: @Rainman Hello friend what is RecursiveTypeProperties referring to? Did you mean to write FindSpecialProperties?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, you have a point. I updated my answer to prevent infinite loop.

Comment: You can't just compare on gethashcode two different objects can have the same hashcode. And a lookup of a list for a contains check is going to be slow, it should be a hashset

Answer (score 1):

You could do it non-recursively by keeping a stack of properties yet-to-visit and a hash set of properties already visited. Then, you can do a while loop on the properties yet-to-visit until you've hit them all.

For example (note: code isn't tested):

```
HashSet<PropertyInfo> visitedProperties = new HashSet<PropertyInfo>();
Stack<PropertyInfo> remainingProperties = new Stack<PropertyInfo>(type.GetProperties());
List<PropertyInfo> foundProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

while (remainingProperties.Count > 0)
{
    var currentProperty = remainingProperties.Pop();

    // Process this property if we haven't visited it yet
    // Add returns true if the element is not yet in the set
    if (visitedProperties.Add(currentProperty))
    {

        // Add sub-properties to the remaining property list if we haven't visited them
        var nestedProperties = currentProperty.PropertyType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var nestedProperty in nestedProperties)
        {
            if (!visitedProperties.Contains(nestedProperty))
            {
                remainingProperties.Push(nestedProperty);
            }
        }

        // Check the current property for attributes
        var singleNestedPropertyIndex = nestedProperty.GetCustomAttribute<SingleIndexAttribute>();
        var groupNestedIndex = nestedProperty.GetCustomAttribute<GroupIndexAttribute>();
        var ttlIndex = property.GetCustomAttribute<TTLIndexAttribute>();

        if (singleNestedPropertyIndex != null || groupNestedIndex != null || ttlIndex != null)
        {
            foundProperties.Add(nestedProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

This will perform in O(N) time, where N is the total number of properties and nested sub-properties in the entire tree.

Comment: Good. There are many other ways you could improve your algorithm. For example: could you make it a lazily-computed `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>` rather than an eagerly-computed `List<PropertyInfo>`?  If you do that then you can use the LINQ sequence operators to build lazily-executed queries.